# How to determine availability of rentals for back to back use using a recursive cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm working on a proc that will determine whether or not an entity has enough rental equipment to cover all of its rentals during a set period of time.

We also have a new feature that allows customers to pickup their equipment while the location is closed.

However, we also allow back to back rentals, meaning a single piece of equipment can have multiple rentals while the entity is closed.

I need a way to determine (Assuming all rentals are picked up and returned on time) whether or not there is enough equipment to cover all reservations.

I attempted to use a recursive CTE to determine this, but I am not able to push my max recursion limit any further, and as some rentals are less than an hour, I must measure the dates in a maximum of 30 minute blocks.

Though, it is also my first time using a recursive cte so I may have made a mistake.

My example is as follows:

```
ID              PickupTime                      DropOffTime
---     -------------------------------------    ------------------------------------
1    2019-2-28 23:00:00.000 2019-3-01 00:00:00.000
2    2019-3-01 00:00:00.000 2019-3-01 01:00:00.000
3    2019-3-01 04:00:00.000 2019-3-01 07:00:00.000
4    2019-2-28 22:00:00.000 2019-2-28 23:00:00.000
5    2019-2-2819:00:00.000  2019-2-28 21:00:00.000
6    2019-2-28 20:00:00.000 2019-2-28 22:00:00.000
7    2019-2-28 23:00:00.000 2019-3-01 01:00:00.000
8    2019-2-28 23:00:00.000 2019-3-01 01:00:00.000
9    2019-3-01 00:00:00.000 2019-3-01 02:00:00.000
10  2019-2-28 21:00:00.000  2019-2-28 22:00:00.000
11  2019-2-28 22:00:00.000  2019-2-28 23:00:00.000

And Equipment

ID    EquipmentNumber
--    ---------------
1     AB123
2     AC321
3     BL854
```

Due to figuring this out on paper, I know that a minimum of 4 equipment is needed to cover these. So this should return a boolean stating yes or no (In this case a no) if all reservations are able to be covered.

This is what I tried:

```
    DECLARE @MinprefDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(PreferredPickupDate) FROM #Results)
    DECLARE @MaxprefDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(PreferredPickupDate) FROM #Results)
    DECLARE @MinexpDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(ExpectedReceiveDate) FROM #Results)
    DECLARE @MaxexpDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(ExpectedReceiveDate) FROM #Results)

    ;WITH CTE AS (
                    SELECT 1 AS n, r.ID, r.ContractID, @MinprefDate AS PreferredPickupDate, @MinexpDate AS ExpectedReceiveDate, r.PreviousPickup, r.PreviousExpected, r.NextPickup, r.NextExpected 
                    FROM #Results r

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT n + 1, ID, ContractID, DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @MinprefDate), DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @MaxexpDate), PreviousPickup, PreviousExpected, NextPickup, NextExpected FROM CTE
                    WHERE ExpectedReceiveDate <= @MaxexpDate
                    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE OPTION (MaxRecursion 3000)
```

Comment: Your data doesn't make sense.  How can the drop off time before the pickup time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume that your times are wrapping around, so 01:00:00 really means 25:00:00, then I rather understand your problem.

I'm not quite sure how to handle ties, but the following returns what you want:

```
select top (1) t.id, v.time, sum(inc) over (order by time, id) as overlaps
from t cross apply
     (values (pickuptime, 1), (dropofftime, -1)) v(time, inc)
order by overlaps desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=caa8f6b897306f099d46d0f292b8c1c7) is a db<>fiddle.

There is no need to use recursive CTEs.  You simply need to account for each pickup and dropoff, which you can do with a cumulative sum.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. This is a 24 hour clock so 01:00 is 1 a.m. the next day. I should have had the dates in the original post. Would this method still work that way? The column data type is a datetime.

Comment: @Taktical1 . . . Yes, this method will still work with date times.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Thanks so much! I applied this to my proc and tested it against a few different scenarios. This works exactly how I need it to.